# What does "*&n" mean in double-pointer c++?

Tags: c++

here it is the code that the teacher gave me to solve in a quiz. can you explain to me what is the *&n do or print out?

first of all: is it even possible to have such a thing?

```cpp
int x = 5;
int* p = &x;
int** n = &p;

std::cout << *&n;
```

Comment: `n` is a pointer to pointer to int thus de-referencing address of `n`  you get the value in `n` which is pointer `p`. But what is the point in doing so? `cout << *&x;`  even being correct but there is no point there.

Comment: Is there a reason you haven't checked with your compiler's C++ language reference to see what each operator does?

Comment: Read https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access

Comment: @ThomasSablik Thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*&n` is equivalent to `n`. Thus the value of `n` is printed out.

The value of `n` is the address of the variable `p` that is a pointer to `int`.

Comment: `*&n` is only equivalent to `n` if `n` is a primitive (like in this case), if it is an instance of the class it is only guaranteed to be `n` if the `operator &` is not overloaded.

Comment: Obviously, the answer is talking about this particular case.

Comment: I know and I just wanted to mention it informatively for the sake of completeness. As someone that does not know what `*` and `&` does most certainly also does not know that this is only guaranteed for primitives.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    int* p = &x;
    int** n = &p;
    int a = 3;

    std::cout << **n << std::endl;
    std::cout << *&**n << std::endl;

    std::cout << &**n << std::endl;
    std::cout << *n << std::endl;

    std::cout << *&a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

`*n` writes what `n` points to.
`&n` writes the address of `n`.
The address of a variable points to the value of that variable.

I think you can deduce the rest from the example.

Comment: The explanation for `*n` and `&n` is only true for primitives (like in the given question), for instance of an object, it might be different, as the behavior of `&` and `*` can be overwritten.